# pyspark when/otherwise clause failure when using udf

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a udf function which takes the `key` and return the corresponding `value` from `name_dict`.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, when, col

name_dict = {'James': "manager", 'Robert': 'director'}
func = udf(lambda name: name_dict[name])
```

The original dataframe: `James` and `Robert` are in the dict, but `Michael` is not.

```
data = [("James","M"),("Michael","M"),("Robert",None)]
test = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = ['name', 'gender'])
test.show()
```

```
+-------+------+
|   name|gender|
+-------+------+
|  James|     M|
|Michael|     M|
| Robert|  null|
+-------+------+
```

To prevent `KeyError`, I use the `when` condition to filter the rows before any operation, but it does not work.

```
test.withColumn('senior', when(col('name').isin(['James', 'Robert']), func(col('name'))).otherwise(col('gender'))).show()
```

> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'KeyError:
> 'Michael'', from , line 8. Full traceback
> below...

What is the cause of this and are there any feasible ways to solve this problem? Assume that not all the names are keys of the dictionary and for those that are not included, I would like to copy the value from another column, say `gender` here.

Answer (score 3):

This actually the behavior of user-defined functions in Spark. You can read from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html):

> The user-defined functions do not support conditional expressions or
> short circuiting in boolean expressions and it ends up with being
> executed all internally. If the functions can fail on special rows,
> the workaround is to incorporate the condition into the functions.

So in your case you need to rewrite your UDF as:

```
func = udf(lambda name: name_dict.get(name, "NA"))
```

Then calling it using:

```
test.withColumn('senior', func(col('name'))).show()

#+-------+------+--------+
#|   name|gender|  senior|
#+-------+------+--------+
#|  James|     M| manager|
#|Michael|     M|      NA|
#| Robert|  null|director|
#+-------+------+--------+
```

However, in you case you can actually do this without having to use udf, by using a map column:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit

map_col = create_map(*[lit(x) for x in chain(*name_dict.items())])
test.withColumn('senior', map_col[col('name')]).show()
```